# Why does different container of same elasticsearch image on docker exits out?

Tags: image, elasticsearch, docker, containers, exit

I am trying to run same Elastic Search image twice, but one container exits out. Only one elasticsearch container runs, others exits out. Any solution/ suggestion would be helpful. I ran it with following command:

```
docker run -d my_es:v3 elasticsearch
```

below is the log file for the process which is getting exited.

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01:~/AnyElastic# docker logs e2cbd47927af
[2016-06-16 21:36:12,339][INFO ][node                     ] [Angela Del Toro] version[2.3.3], pid[1], build[218bdf1/2016-05-17T15:40:04Z]
[2016-06-16 21:36:12,343][INFO ][node                     ] [Angela Del Toro] initializing ...
[2016-06-16 21:36:14,014][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Angela Del Toro] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-06-16 21:36:14,053][INFO ][env                      ] [Angela Del Toro] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/vda1)]], net usable_space [13.9gb], net total_space [19.5gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2016-06-16 21:36:14,053][INFO ][env                      ] [Angela Del Toro] heap size [1015.6mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-06-16 21:36:20,241][INFO ][node                     ] [Angela Del Toro] initialized
[2016-06-16 21:36:20,241][INFO ][node                     ] [Angela Del Toro] starting ...
[2016-06-16 21:36:20,400][INFO ][transport                ] [Angela Del Toro] publish_address {172.17.0.3:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2016-06-16 21:36:20,407][INFO ][discovery                ] [Angela Del Toro] elasticsearch/ketVVDMtQCeBwj-x64E5yQ
[2016-06-16 21:36:23,565][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Angela Del Toro] new_master {Angela Del Toro}{ketVVDMtQCeBwj-x64E5yQ}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-06-16 21:36:23,605][INFO ][http                     ] [Angela Del Toro] publish_address {172.17.0.3:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2016-06-16 21:36:23,607][INFO ][node                     ] [Angela Del Toro] started
[2016-06-16 21:36:23,670][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Angela Del Toro] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

Comment: Can you post how run the container? I think, it is probably port conflict.

Comment: I ran with this command:docker run -d my_es:v3 elasticsearch

Comment: Can you post anything that could help? Log output or output from the `docker` command?

Comment: What is the purpose of my_es:v3? I think it is the problem.

Comment: my_es:v3 is the image name

Comment: I actually have a nasty feeling here that your kernel OOM (out-of-memory) killer is kicking in. From the machine hostname, I'm assuming that you only have 512MB of RAM in your machine, and ElasticSearch is assuming it has a 1GB heap. Do a few things: run `docker stats` on the working container to figure out how much RAM it is using, run `free -m` to find out how much RAM you have left, and then run `dmesg` and look for anything mentioning "OOM" to see if something is getting OOM killed.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, the memory was the issue. Now both of my images are up and running. I cleared some docker images and it has sufficient space now. Thanks for help slugonamission :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by looking at the logs, the memory is the issue, since there is only 512mb ram on linux box and there were many containers running at that time, so other container of elasticsearch would exit out. This something which nobody has encountered before. Conclusion: Port is not the issue, you can run same images many times provided you have sufficient ram to run those docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

I think my_es:v3 is the problem for you. If you are trying to name your container use `--name` option. Also you can't ':' in the name.

```
docker run -d --name my_es elasticsearch
```

Comment: I dont think : is the problem, it a way to define a tag. The image name is my_es and the tag is v3. So thats not the problem

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was confused with the `elasticsearch` in your run command. Since it the the default entry point, you can ignore it when running. `docker run -d my_es:v3` would be enough.

Comment: I have specified the CMD in dockerfile as elasticsearch, hence i had added elasticsearch in the run command

Comment: Okies.. slugionamission's solution solved your problem. Great.. :).